# corregir o agregar protecciones Scripting y Tokens anti-CSRF en sistema PHP

Tags: php, tokens, php8, scripting

estoy intentando publicar un sistema PHP, sin embargo al momento de realizar un test básico salen estas alertas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

según la imagen, estas advertencias suceden específicamente en 2 archivos los cuales son **index.php** y **validacion.php**, el index es el login para iniciar sesion, y el archivo validacion valida que usuario esta ingresando, hasta este punto la verdad es que no se como hacer para arreglar y que ya no salgan esas alertas o errores y de paso aprender de ello

estos son mis códigos, del archivo **index.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();   // Necesitamos una sesion
  if(isset($SESSION['u_usuario'])){  // comparamos si existe
    header("Location: validacion.php"); // si existe, lo redireccionamos a sesion.php
  }
  else{
    session_destroy();  // si no existe, destruimos sesion
  }
?>﻿


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Favicon - FIS -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/Logo-fis.png">

  <!-- My Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">

  <title>Sistema de encuestas</title>
</head>
<body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Sistema de Encuestas</a>
      <!--
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      -->

      <!--NAVBAR-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <!--
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          -->
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <!--
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          -->
          <!--
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html" role="button">Ingresar</a>
          -->
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!--LOGIN-->

     <div class="container">
        <div class="card card-container">
            <!-- <img class="profile-img-card" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="" /> -->
            <img   src="imagenes/Logo-fis.png" />
            <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
            <form class="form-signin" action="validacion.php" method="POST">
                <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus name="id_usuario">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required name="clave">
                <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
                    <!--
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                    </label>
                     -->
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
                <!--
                  <input type="submit" name="" value="Ingresar">
                -->
            </form><!-- /form -->
        </div><!-- /card-container -->
    </div><!-- /container -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="page-footer font-small" style="background-color: #343A40; color: #FFF; margin-top: 150px">

      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2022 Todos los derechos reservados
        <br>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"> Banrural Honduras</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->

    </footer>
    <!-- Footer -->


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

y **validacion.php**

```
<?php   

session_start();

$id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
echo $id_usuario;
$clave  = $_POST['clave'];
echo $clave;
include("conexion.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM sistema_encuestasv1.usuarios WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario' AND clave = '$clave'";
    
    $resultado = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
    
    
    if ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)) {


        if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '1') {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: administrador/index.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: usuario/index.php");
        }
        
        if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '3') {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: usuario_vista/index.php");
        }

    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if (!$query) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        exit();
    }

 ?>
```

Alguien que porfavor me ayude con esto, ya que si me urge y es algo nuevo para mi y no se puede publicar sin antes resolver esto

Comment: ¿sabes que puedes pedir la [combinación de perfiles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)?  esta misma pregunta la has hecho hace 5 horas con el perfil de un tal @Mchavez9494bl, aunque ahora ya está eliminada.  Aparte de eso, en cuanto a la pregunta, no he entendido antes ni ahora de donde sacas ese "test básico"... ¿como se hace eso?... ¿y porque da esos errores en un código que aparentemente es normal?... quizas si nos cuentas co que herramienta consigues esos errores podremos entender mejor como ayudarte, gracias.

Comment: Mil disculpas por la tardanza, pues la verdad el area encargada de publicar el sistema me dio esa información, desconozco que aplicativos utiliza o como se hace ya que no me dijeron